# Question filtering menu displays partly off small screens

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, mobile-chrome

While using the **Chrome** browser on my **iPhone SE**, I noticed the question filtering menu displayed partly off the screen.

> [image: Question filtering menu partly off screen]

Then I repro'd this behavior on my laptop using Chrome and reducing the screen width.

> [image: Question filtering menu partly off screen]

**Update:**

Looks like the question filtering menu has been fixed, even for my iPhone SE. Thank you!

> [image: Question filtering menu]

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out! As we go through and make the site responsive, page by page we are tackling these things. This is on our radar. Appreciated!

Comment: See my update. The issue has been resolved. :-)